# Is it possible to make the img tag display svg images that cointain addresses inside it?

Tags: html, svg

I have created the following SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="150" height="150">
    <rect
        x="5"
        y="5"
        width="140"
        height="140"
        style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1"
        id="rect2" 
    />
    <image
        y="50"
        x="80"
        id="image76"
        xlink:href='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/46/46441.svg'
        preserveAspectRatio="none"
        height="60"
        width="60" 
    />
    <image
        y="50"
        x="10"
        id="image76"
        xlink:href='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Android_robot.png/646px-Android_robot.png'
        preserveAspectRatio="none"
        height="60"
        width="60"
    />
</svg>
```

I've managed to display it using the `object` tag like the following and it works fine:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>
```

The result is like this:

[image]

---

However, when I try to use the `img` tag I have the following result:

```
<img src="image.svg"/>
```

[image]

When I try to display this svg file with the `img` tag, the images that are inside it disappear. I know it happens because I'm using addresses like https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/46/46441.svg and https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Android_robot.png/646px-Android_robot.png for my images instead of writing a base64 image inside this svg. But because it's possible with the `object` tag I'm curious to know if it's also possible with the `img` tag. Is it possible to make the `img` tag open svg files like this one? Or is it a limitation of the `img` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No documents loaded in `<img>` can not request any external resource, can not execute scripts, can not receive any user event.

For your bitmap image, you'd have to embedded it as a `data:` URI in the svg itself.